# Form - Passing array from controller to view - PHP - Laravel

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, view, controller

I'm really new to Laravel, and I'm not sure that I know what I'm doing. I have a form in my main view. I'm passing the input to a controller, and I want the data to be displayed in another view. I can't seem to get the array from the controller to the second view. I keep getting 500 hphp_invoke. Here's where I'm passing the array from the controller to view2.

```
public function formSubmit()
{
    if (Input::post())
    {
        $name = Input::get('name');
        $age = Input::get('age');
        $things = array($name, $age);
        return View::make('view2', array('things'=>$things));
    }
}
```

view1.blade.php

```
{{ Form::open(array('action' => 'controller@formSubmit')) }}
    <p>{{ Form::label('Name') }}
    {{ $name = Form::text('name') }}</p>
    <p>{{ Form::label('Age') }}
    {{ $age = Form::text('age') }}</p>
    <p>{{ Form::submit('Submit') }}</p>
{{ Form::close() }}
```

My view2.php file is really simple.

```
<?php
    echo $name;
    echo $age;
?>
```

Then in routes.php

```
Route::get('/', function()
{
    return View::make('view1');
});
Route::post('view2', 'controller@formSubmit');
```

Why isn't this working?

Answer (score 7):

try **with()**

```
$data = array(
    'name'  => $name,
    'age' => $age
);

return View::make('view2')->with($data);
```

on view get :-
        echo $data['name'];
        echo $data['age'];

or

```
return View::make('view2')->with(array('name' =>$name, 'age' => $age));
```

get on view :-

```
echo $name;
echo $age;
```

For more Follow [here](http://weblint4u.com/pass-data-from-controller-to-view-laravel/)

Comment: Thanks for your help. That doesn't seem to be working though. Could it be the route that I have? It's Route::post('view2','controller@formSubmit'); Is that wrong?

Comment: I added more of my code. Nothing that I change seems to be working. Do you see anything else wrong with what I have?

Answer (score 3):

You need to use:

```
return View::make('view2')->with(['name' => $name, 'age' => $age]);
```

to use

`$name` and `$age` in your template

Answer (score 2):

Since `$things` is already an `array` so you may use following approach but make the array associative:

```
$name = Input::get('name');
$age = Input::get('age');
$things = array('name' => $name, 'age' => $age);
return View::make('view2', $things);
```

So, you can access `$name` and `$age` in your `view`. Also, you may try this:

```
return View::make('view2')->with('name', $name)->with('age', $age);
```

Answer (score 2):

In your controller, use

```
return View::make('view2')->with($things);
```

In your view, you can now access each attribute using

```
@foreach($things as $thing)
    <p>{{ $thing->name }}</p>
    <p>{{ $thing->age }}</p>
@endforeach
```